# SQL with JOIN and Group By Plus Average

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am looking to generate results of my shop efficiencies. To do this I will need data from 3 different tables JOMAST, JODRTG and INRTGS. So I have come up with the following Query:

```
select jomast.fpartno AS 'Part Number',
JODRTG.foperno AS 'OP Number',
JODRTG.fopermemo As ' Description',
JODRTG.fpro_id AS 'Work Center',
jodrtg.fprod_tim AS ' Act. Production Time',
inrtgs.fuprodtime AS 'Est. Prodution Time'
from jodrtg
Left join jomast on jodrtg.fjobno = jomast.fjobno
left join inrtgs on jomast.fpartno = inrtgs.fpartno
```

Now what I need to do is average out the Act. Production Time. And get things down to the Part Number with all of the OP numbers for that part.

When I try and `Group By JOMAST.fpartno` I get an error that it cannot use and outer column. If I do Group By on the Operation number, then all Operation 10's for every part will be combined. Which, is not the desired result.

Can someone please point me in the direction I need to go to achieve my result?

Comment: You can't group by an outer reference.  If this was allowed, it would essentially turn your outer join to an inner join - and that's obviously not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to have multiple rows all showing the same `jodrtg.fpartno`, all showing different `jodrtg.fprod_tim`, but all showing the average (same) value of `jodrtg.fprod_tim` yes?

If so, add:

```
AVG(jodrtg.fprod_tim) OVER(PARTITION BY jodrtg.fpartno) as avg_for_all_fprod_tim
```

as a column in your list of columns you're selecting.

For more info you can google PARTITION BY, but think of it like an instruction to perform a GROUP BY x, AVG(y) (or sum, max, whatever) on the data, but then put that AVG into the row data for each row where x is present..

Essentially it's the same as writing a smaller subquery of `(SELECT jodrtg.fpartno, avg(jodrtg.fprod_tim) as avg_for_all_frod_tim FROM blah GROUP BY jodrtg.fpartno)` and then joining it back to your main query

Comment: Sort of. I am wanting to average all of JODRTG.foperno that equal 10 for jomast.fpartno. The JODRTG table does not contain the Part Number. It does have the Job Number, which I can use in the JOMAST table to get the Part Number. The inrtgs.fuprodtime is our default "This is how long this operation should take" time. So I want to compare that with the Average of our Actual to see if we need to be making changes. I deally I would like something like: Row 1 Part Number/Colm 6" C Operation Number/10 Operation Memo/Something here Work Center/78-01 Act Prod Time/2.56 Est. Prod Time/.63